# Is char the only type with a mandated size?

Tags: c++, sizeof

In the C++ standard:

> `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are `1`.

1. Are there any other types in C++ which have a fixed `sizeof`?
2. Does the empty structure correspond to this definition?

Comment: The fixed size of `char` is because it's the smallest addressable unit on any system. And no, no other type have this requirement. And yes empty structures need to have a size (or they won't be addressable) so their size is (at least) one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. No. As you say, `sizeof(signed char)`, `sizeof(unsigned char)`, and `sizeof(char)` are defined by the standard to be 1. Note that `char` must be either `signed` or `unsigned` but it is always considered to be a distinct type. The `sizeof` anything else is down to the implementation subject to some constraints (e.g. `sizeof(long)` cannot be less than `sizeof(int)`.)
2. The C++ standard requires `sizeof` an empty class to be an integral value greater than zero (otherwise pointer arithmetic would break horribly).

Comment: Then empty structure may have different sizes greater than zero, depending on the machine architecture?

Comment: @МирасАмир Absolutely.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes you are correct and to confirm my descent into senility, I  answered a question on that a few weeks go so ought to have known better. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, it's not that bad for a cat :)

Comment: Maybe, just for complete the answer, you should talk about the types uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t and uint64_t (and their signed equivalent), which are also requiered to have a fixed size across implementations...

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Are there any other types in C++ which have a fixed sizeof?

There are arrays which have specified size:

```
sizeof(T[N]) == N * sizeof(T)
```

so `sizeof(char[42])` is `42`.

> 2) Does the empty structure correspond to this definition?

Empty struct is neither `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char`, so it doesn't correspond to this definition. (BTW its `sizeof` cannot be `0`).

Answer (score -1):

Regarding question 1, you also have the types in `stdint.h`.